"Tail -f" on symlink that points to a file on another drive has interval stops, but not when tailing the original file
I'm encountering a strange behaviour with tail -f, when tailing a symlink on an Ubuntu machine.
Apparently, tail uses the default update interval of 1 second. If tailing the original file, it seems to update immediately.
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Sep  9 20:28 firewall_log-01.log -> /var/data/log/firewall_log-01.log

Doing
$ tail -f firewall_log-01.log

"pauses" every second (roughly, haven't measured exactly), which fits the defaults for tail:
-s, --sleep-interval=N
with -f, sleep for approximately N seconds (default 1.0)

When doing
$ tail -f /var/data/log/firewall_log-01.log

the output gets updated immediately, apparently not concerned with the default setting for interval.
When I run tail -s 0.01:
$ tail -f -s 0.01 firewall_log-01.log

I basically have what I need, but I'm still confused by why this even happens.
I can do a workaround by adding an alias to ~/.bashrc, but this seems like a kind of dirty workaround.
Is there any logical reason for tail to behave like this?

GNU tail uses inotify on Linux when it can to detect when there's new data. See the undocumented ---disable-inotify to disable it so you get the usual poll every second.

See also "tail -s N" does not sleep for N seconds before updating

---disable-inotify does not change the behaviour in my case, unfortunately.

---disable-inotify would consistently do the 1 every second poll, it would not enable inotify wherever it's otherwise disabled like for symlinks.

On Linux-based systems, GNU tail uses the inotify feature to detect when there are changes to files. That way it doesn't need to poll every second (or whatever you specify for -s).
It is a bit brittle though and there are several corner cases for which it doesn't work properly (see this or that bugs).
When the file is a symlink it gives up using inotify and falls back to the traditional polling. The justification in the code reads:

any_symlinks() checks if the user has specified any symbolic links.
inotify is not used in this case because it returns updated targets
which would not match the specified names.  If we tried to always
use the target names, then we would miss changes to the symlink itself.
ok is false when one of the files specified could not be opened for
reading.  In this case and when following by descriptor,
tail_forever_inotify() cannot be used (in its current implementation).
FIXME: inotify doesn't give any notification when a new
(remote) file or directory is mounted on top a watched file.
When follow_mode == Follow_name we would ideally like to detect that.
Note if there is a change to the original file then we'll
recheck it and follow the new file, or ignore it if the
file has changed to being remote.
FIXME-maybe: inotify has a watch descriptor per inode, and hence with
our current hash implementation will only --follow data for one
of the names when multiple hardlinked files are specified, or
for one name when a name is specified multiple times.

Here, if using zsh, you could do:
tail -f -- file(:P)

Instead of tail -f file, to follow the file using a symlink-free path to maximize the chance of inotify being used to follow it.
Or with any POSIX-like shell or recent versions of fish, assuming the realpath of the file doesn't end in newline characters:
tail -f -- "$(realpath file)"

